# Imager plugin using it's transformImage method doesn't produce correctly resized images

Tags: image-transforms, plugin-imager

I'm using the lovely "Imager" plugin to produce a srcset of images, however it seems to only produce one size of image, which isn't really what i was expecting!

My code is:

```
{% set image = entry.image.first() %}
{% set transformedImages = craft.imager.transformImage(image, [
    { width: 1370, height: 600 },
    { width: 1000 },
    { width: 800 },
    { width: 600, jpegQuality: 65 },
    { width: 400, jpegQuality: 65 }
], { position: image.focalPoint, mode: 'crop', jpegQuality: 80 }) %}
```

Have i missed something here?

Comment: What size image is being produced? How are you testing it? Are you visiting the URL with appropriately sized browser windows to trigger the different sized images?

Comment: Can you share the HTML that it's generating?

Comment: @BradBell i'm an idiot, it was the chrome devtools lying to me about the real image sizes. I loaded them up into the browser and they were the right sizes. That was using them with srcset. Damn you google chrome! Damn youuuuu!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out google chrome dev tools was lying to me when i hovered over the images in a srcset and told me their natural size was different to their real size. All working grand!